# How to use Hibernate multi-tenancy from JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I'm able to use hibernate multi-tenancy directly using hibernate but my requirement is to use hibernate from jpa.
Using Hibernate SessionFactory from hibernate :

```
 SessionFactory factory1=HibernateUtil.getSession();
      Session session1=factory1.withOptions().tenantIdentifier("db2").openSession();
      session1.beginTransaction();
```

With JPA

```
    EntityManagerFactory factory=JpaUtil.getEntityManagerFactory();
    EntityManager em=factory.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
```

with this i'm getting following as expected EntityManager creating SessionFactory without `factory1.withOptions().tenantIdentifier("db2").openSession();`

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: SessionFactory configured for multi-tenancy, but no tenant identifier specified
```

How can i resolve this error ? or Is there some other way to use Hibernate Multi-tenancy with JPA?

my persistence.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

<persistence-unit name="myJpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>com.nuc.jpa.MyEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root123" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="SCHEMA" />
        <property name="hibernate.multi_tenant_connection_provider" value="com.nuc.MultiTenantConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.tenant_identifier_resolver" value="com.nuc.MCurrentTenantIdentifierResolver"/> 
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35030733/3459206

Comment: Is the spring tag relevant for this question? I see nothing in the question itself that would indicate Spring is used