# How do manage multiiple transaction managers (for multi-tenancy) in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We are using **Spring Boot** with [Spring Data JPA](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) with the Transactional annotation for managing transactions.

However, we have a multi-tenant application and for very large customers, we need to put them on a separate dedicated DB.

Is there any way to intercept with TransactionManager is used by the TransactionalAnnotation and dynamically override it per request (depending which tenant is getting updated)?

Comment: This may help https://tech.asimio.net/2017/01/17/Multitenant-applications-using-Spring-Boot-JPA-Hibernate-and-Postgres.html

Comment: You don't (and shouldn't) worry about the `TransactionManager` in a multi-tenant application developed using Spring Transactions. Rather, you should make sure that for every operation, the JPA `EntityManager` has access to the right `DataSource` appropriate for the tenant associated with the operation. When using Hibernate as the JPA provider, there are several strategies for finding the right `DataSource` for an operation, if the tenant can be identified correctly. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35024025/spring-data-jpa-with-multi-tenancy-hibernate) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very useful [link](https://sunitkatkar.blogspot.com/2018/05/adding-tenants-without-application.html) for your need, implementing multitenancy in spring boot with spring data Jpa, 
It saves the list of tenants in a master(common) database and Hibernate manages the multitenancy datasources (seperate Databases per tenant).